# Sql Total Sum using no of row counts in a table

Tags: sql-server, join, count, sum

i am trying to find the total marks for each student based on StudentId and MarksTypeId row count.

i have 3 tables

```
MarksType

----------------------------------
MarksTypeId |  MarkType    | Marks   
----------------------------------
1           |    Writing   | 10        
2           |    Drawing   | 30        
3           |    Singing   | 20    
----------------------------------     

Students

--------------------------------
StudentId |  Name    | Address
--------------------------------
1         |    John  | USA     
2         |    Raja  | India       
3         |    Paul  | AUS     
--------------------------------   

MarksDetails      --  Has two foreign keys

-------------------------------------------------------   
MarksDetailsId |  MarksTypeId    |  StudentId | Date
-------------------------------------------------------
1              |    3            | 1          | 18 jan
2              |    3            | 1          | 18 jan
3              |    1            | 3          | 19 jan
-------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my Desired Result :

```
------------------------------------
StudentId |  Name     | Total Marks
------------------------------------
1         |    John   | 40     
2         |    Raja   | 0      
3         |    Paul   | 10     
------------------------------------
```

i mean if John sang two times a day, so using StudentId and MarksTypeId, i need his total Marks as result.

so far i did the following:

```
select  Sum(MarksType.Marks)  from MarksType inner join MarksDetails    on   MarksType.MarksTypeId=1
```

but the sum returns wrong total,

UPDATED OTHER ATTEMPTS:

1. this results total row count for each studentid

   ```
   select MarksDetails.StudentId , COUNT(MarksDetails.StudentId ) as     count   from MarksDetails
   group by MarksDetails.StudentId
   ```
2. this results Marks, with studentid and markstypeid

   ```
   select  MarksType.Marks, MarksType.MarksTypeId , MarksDetails.StudentId   from MarksType inner join MarksDetails  on   MarksType.MarksTypeId =    MarksDetails.StudentId
   ```

may i know what i am doing wrong. 
Any help would be Great.

Comment: Because you limit your results to MarksDetailId=1.   Why did you do that?

Comment: also you are not joining correctly and missing third table

Comment: You need to have a group by in there also.

Comment: @Tab Alleman , i just gave attempt for particular id, i have updated with two more query

Comment: @Darka, yes joining  third table will help , may i know based on row counts and total sum

Comment: @Sean Lange, i have updated with two queries,  see were changes can be made

Comment: I dont think that `LoayaltyPoints_T.MarksTypeId =    MarksDetails.StudentId` this is equal.

Comment: The query #1 above is closer...don't you need the MarksType so you know what the value is? Also, shouldn't it be sum and not count?

Comment: @Darka, thanks for pointing out that, it was a typing mistake

Comment: @Sean Lange , i tried markstype and sum, but i need total marks for each student based on markstypeid and stuendtid, can you edit my query, i am learning

Comment: If I edit it you don't learn anything. You need all three tables for this to work right? First get all three tables in your query, then all you need is to get the total value of MarksType.

Comment: @Sean Lange thanks for not editing the query, you made me to learn, i have posted the answer. any good resource to learn sql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally with kind guidance from sql developers and after making some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505268/join-three-tables-with-sum-of-column-in-access-query), here is the query with desired result, maybe useful for someone, enjoy !

```
SELECT Student.StudentId, Student.Name, sum(MarksType.Marks) as TotalMarks
FROM
 MarksType
INNER JOIN
 MarksDetails on MarksType.MarksTypeId = MarksDetails.MarksTypeId
INNER  JOIN 
 Student on Student.StudentId =  MarksDetails.StudentId

 group by Student.Name,Student.StudentId
```