# SQL statements In Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have attached the 3 tables I have below.

Trainers table

[image]

TrainerPlan Table

[image]

FitnessPlans Table

[image]

So what I am trying to do is show the FirstName, LastName, Phone, and Hours of all trainers who have a particular PlanID. So I tried

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Phone, Hours
FROM TRAINERS T INNER JOIN TRAINERPLAN TP
ON T.ID = TP.TrainerID
INNER JOIN FITNESSPLANS FP
ON TP.PlanID = FP.ID
WHERE FP.ID = 1;
```

I get the error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I have done sql in sql developer and this is how I would do it. I'm pretty sure access sql is not exactly the same, but if I run:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Phone, Hours
FROM TRAINERS T INNER JOIN TRAINERPLAN TP
ON T.ID = TP.TrainerID;
```

This runs successfully and shows results, so I know the inner joining is working, but I just can't get another inner join on there for some reason.

Comment: Access has some funky syntax requirements which force you to parenthesize multiple joins. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7855015/621962)

Comment: Set up your joins in Design View of the Access query designer.  It will add the required parentheses for you.

Comment: Yet another reason why I loathe MS Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access "nests" joins, which requires that they be in parentheses:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Phone, Hours
FROM ((TRAINERS T INNER JOIN TRAINERPLAN TP
ON T.ID = TP.TrainerID)
INNER JOIN FITNESSPLANS FP
ON TP.PlanID = FP.ID)
WHERE FP.ID = 1;
```