# Need to debug Left Join in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2010

Help, I'm new to SQL, and new to Stack Overflow!

I am receiving a "Syntax Error", which only seems to occur with the 2nd Left Join (without it, the code runs fine). Here is my code, being compiled by Access 2010:

```
SELECT      Billings.[CustomerNumber], 
            Billings.[Customer Name], 
            Billings.[SOP Number], 
            Billings.[Item Number], 
            Sum (Billings.[Extended Price]) AS ['Revenue'], 
            Sum (Billings.QTY) AS ['Quantity']
FROM        [Product Codes]         AS Codes
LEFT JOIN   Billings                ON Codes.[Product Code] = Billings.[Item Number]
LEFT JOIN   [All Rep Assignments]   ON Billings.CustomerNumber = [All Rep Assignments].[Account Number]
GROUP BY    Billings.[CustomerNumber], 
            Billings.[Customer Name], 
            Billings.[SOP Number], 
            Billings.[Item Number]
```

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: if you are using Access, why not use the query-builder to create your query visually, then you can see how the builder constructs the clauses :)

Comment: Post your table schema please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parentheses when having multiple joins (1 for each)

[SQL multiple join statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854969/sql-multiple-join-statement)

```
SELECT      Billings.[CustomerNumber], 
            Billings.[Customer Name], 
            Billings.[SOP Number], 
            Billings.[Item Number], 
            Sum (Billings.[Extended Price]) AS ['Revenue'], 
            Sum (Billings.QTY) AS ['Quantity']
FROM        (([Product Codes]         AS Codes
LEFT JOIN   Billings                
ON Codes.[Product Code] = Billings.[Item Number])
LEFT JOIN   [All Rep Assignments]   
ON Billings.CustomerNumber = [All Rep Assignments].[Account Number])
GROUP BY    Billings.[CustomerNumber], 
            Billings.[Customer Name], 
            Billings.[SOP Number], 
            Billings.[Item Number]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL as shown is from the Access query builder using SQL view, be aware Access is sensitive about white-space.  Make sure your lines end with a space.  (I notice there is no semi-colon at the end, which is required in that view.)

If your code is from somewhere else, like a VBA module, then move that SQL over to the Access query builder using SQL view and trouble-shoot from there.  (With a semi-colon at the end.)  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/122139) for more.