# Getting data from a join tables tu sub categories in access with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I created this relationship with Access database but when I am creating a query to return the values I dont get the all the data. 
[image]
How can I get all the data from `tube` and `tmc` tables by `ProjectType` or `ProjectId` ?

So I should get something like this query but the query generated by access is not working

```
    SELECT Project.ProjectName, 
           ProjectSubTypesId.ProjectSubTypesId, 
           Tube.TubeName, Tube.Duration, 
           Tmc.TmcName
   FROM Tmc 
INNER JOIN 
(Tube INNER JOIN 
  (Project INNER JOIN ProjectSubTypesId ON Project.ProjectId = ProjectSubTypesId.ProjectId) 
ON Tube.TubeId = ProjectSubTypesId.TubeId) ON Tmc.TmcId = ProjectSubTypesId.TmcId;
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  A SQL Fiddle is also helpful, although you will have to use a different database from MS Access.

Comment: The issues is with Access in a regular database cascade inner join probably work. The result is just if  a project has two subtype of project kind tube the result will be to row with the name of the project and the TubeName and Duration

Comment: I added a sample of the database so it maybe helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Project.ProjectName, 
       ProjectSubTypesId.ProjectSubTypesId
    FROM (
       (ProjectSubTypes
           INNER JOIN Project USING (ProjectId)
       )
           INNER JOIN Tube USING(TubeId)
       )
           INNER JOIN Tmc USING(TmcId)
GROUP BY ProjectSubTypes.ProjectId, ProjectSubTypes.TubeId, ProjectSubTypes.TmcId
ORDER BY ProjectSubTypes.ProjectId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this work?

```
SELECT Project.ProjectName, 
       ProjectSubTypesId.ProjectSubTypesId, 
       Tube.TubeName, Tube.Duration, 
       Tmc.TmcName
FROM ((ProjectSubTypes
           INNER JOIN Project ON Project.ProjectId = ProjectSubTypes.ProjectId)
       INNER JOIN Tube ON Tube.TubeId = ProjectSubTypes.TubeId)
INNER JOIN Tmc ON Tmc.TmcId = ProjectSubTypes.TmcId
ORDER BY ProjectSubTypes.ProjectId;
```

This should give you a list of all sub-types along with their corresponding Tube, Tmc, and Project data.

If it is possible to have multiple `ProjectSubTypes` rows with the same `TubeId` and `TmcId` then consider adding this line before the `ORDER BY` line:

```
GROUP BY ProjectSubTypes.ProjectId, ProjectSubTypes.TubeId, ProjectSubTypes.TmcId
```

Comment: Yes this probably work in regular SQL but when I tried it on Access and I am having a syntax missing operator, I don't know if it is because access but it looks good syntax to me

Comment: I've updated my answer because in Access you need to nest each additional join in brackets. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854969/sql-multiple-join-statement

Comment: That did not work that is I think the parenthesis are the issue with access

Comment: I checked that post and was trying moving the parenthesis around but the TSQL engine dont like any combination here is a small sample of the db: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23000869/Database1.zip"  so maybe it work with you I am using Office 2013