# MS Access: Syntax error in FROM Clause

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2013

I'm getting a syntax error pointing to my `FROM` clause, but I can't figure it out. The goal here is to use subqueries to filter and return some information *before* joining.

What I've tried: [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854969/sql-multiple-join-statement) suggested that I surround the 2 `LEFT JOINS` with parentheses. I did so, but it didn't help. Below is the result, and the error I get is in the title.

It may or may not be important to note that before doing the parentheses around both `JOINS`, I was getting the following error: `Syntax error (missing operator in query expression 'tbl_HersheySAPInventory.item = maxdatejob.item LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbo_Item_by_Location_LP_All WHERE qty_on_hand >'.`

```
SELECT 

    tbl_HersheySAPInventory.ID, 
    tbl_HersheySAPInventory.item, 
    dbo_job.job_date, 
    dbo_job.job, 
    dbo_job.suffix,
    Sum(comptable.qty_on_hand) AS SumOfqty_on_hand,
    comptable.whse,
    comptable.product_code

FROM 

    tbl_HersheySAPInventory 

    (LEFT JOIN 

        (SELECT 

            dbo_job.job_date, 
            dbo_job.job, 
            dbo_job.suffix, 
            dbo_job.item AS FG,
            dbo_jobmatl.item

        FROM 

            dbo_job 
            INNER JOIN dbo_jobmatl ON dbo_job.job = dbo_jobmatl.job AND dbo_job.suffix = dbo_jobmatl.suffix 

        WHERE

            dbo_job.item Not Like "Indirect" AND
            dbo_job.job Not Like "C0*" AND
            dbo_job.job Not Like "*R0*"

        ) AS maxdatejob 

    ON tbl_HersheySAPInventory.item = maxdatejob.item)

    (LEFT JOIN

        (SELECT * FROM dbo_Item_by_Location_LP_All WHERE qty_on_hand > 0 AND whse = Forms!MainForm!Combo353)  AS comptable

    ON comptable.item = tbl_HersheySAPInventory.item)


ORDER BY 

    tbl_HersheySAPInventory.item, 
    dbo_job.job_date;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a problem with your parentheses. I have similar issues writing SQL into Access - there seem to be some strange requirements wrapping parens around JOINS and WHERE clauses.

The pseudocode that I recommend trying is:

```
FROM 
(
(
Table A
)
LEFT JOIN
  (
  Subquery1
  )
)
LEFT JOIN
  (
  Subquery2
  )
```

I've taken a stab at updating below. Give this a try and let me know:

```
SELECT 

    tbl_HersheySAPInventory.ID, 
    tbl_HersheySAPInventory.item, 
    dbo_job.job_date, 
    dbo_job.job, 
    dbo_job.suffix,
    comptable.whse,
    comptable.product_code,
    Sum(comptable.qty_on_hand) AS SumOfqty_on_hand    
FROM 
(
(
    tbl_HersheySAPInventory 



    LEFT JOIN 

        (SELECT 

            dbo_job.job_date, 
            dbo_job.job, 
            dbo_job.suffix, 
            dbo_job.item AS FG,
            dbo_jobmatl.item

        FROM 

            dbo_job 
            INNER JOIN dbo_jobmatl ON dbo_job.job = dbo_jobmatl.job AND dbo_job.suffix = dbo_jobmatl.suffix 

        WHERE

            dbo_job.item Not Like "Indirect" AND
            dbo_job.job Not Like "C0*" AND
            dbo_job.job Not Like "*R0*"

        ) AS maxdatejob 

    ON tbl_HersheySAPInventory.item = maxdatejob.item
    )
    )

    LEFT JOIN

        (SELECT * FROM dbo_Item_by_Location_LP_All WHERE qty_on_hand > 0 AND whse = Forms!MainForm!Combo353)  AS comptable

    ON comptable.item = tbl_HersheySAPInventory.item

GROUP BY

    tbl_HersheySAPInventory.ID, 
    tbl_HersheySAPInventory.item, 
    dbo_job.job_date, 
    dbo_job.job, 
    dbo_job.suffix,
    comptable.whse,
    comptable.product_code   


ORDER BY 

    tbl_HersheySAPInventory.item, 
    dbo_job.job_date;
```

Comment: It gave me an error saying that `ID` was not part of an aggregate function.

Comment: I've added a `GROUP BY` clause that should attack that.