# SQL inner join with 3 tables and 2 ids stored in 1 table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, syntax-error, inner-join

Hello i'm trying to join 3 tables , in T1 i have id for T2 and T3. But i always get this error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(T2.id_apartmana = T1.id_apartmana) INNER JOIN tblPacijenti T3 ON (T3.id_pacijenta = T1.id_pacijenta)'.
```

This is my sql code:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblapartmanirezervacije AS T1
       INNER JOIN tblapartmani AS T2
               ON ( T2.id_apartmana = T1.id_apartmana )
       INNER JOIN tblpacijenti T3
               ON ( T3.id_pacijenta = T1.id_pacijenta )
WHERE  T1.status = 'true'
```

I use access database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854969/sql-multiple-join-statement

Comment: Thank you, adding the parenthesis solved the problem. I was actually searching for this before posting the question but i didn't find that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access requires extra parentheses when joining multiple tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM (tblapartmanirezervacije AS T1 INNER JOIN
      tblapartmani AS T2
      ON T2.id_apartmana = T1.id_apartmana
     ) INNER JOIN
     tblpacijenti T3
     ON T3.id_pacijenta = T1.id_pacijenta
WHERE T1.status = 'true'
```

A couple of suggestions:

- Use table aliases that mean something.  `ar` for `tblapartmanirezervacije`, `a` for `tblapartmani`, and so on.  These are much easier to follow than arbitrary aliases.
- List the columns that you want, instead of `select *`, especially when the same column appears in multiple tables.

Comment: Thank you, i already list the columns in the code, but I've just put a star there so it would be more readable, because columns are irrelevant for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

SELECT * FROM tblapartmanirezervacije AS T1 INNER JOIN tblapartmani AS T2 ON T1.id_apartmana = T2.id_apartmana INNER JOIN tblpacijenti T3 ON T1.id_pacijenta = T3.id_pacijenta AND T1.status = 'true'