# Two Inner Joins in OleDb SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010, oledb, oledbcommand

I'm trying to make an SQL query with an OleDbCommand into an Access database (.accdb).

While this command works fine (in a `OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()`):

```
string command =
   "SELECT cred.* " +
   "FROM TB_CREDENTIALS cred " +
   "INNER JOIN TB_REL_USERS_CREDENTIALS rel ON cred.CRED_ID = rel.REL_USR_CRED_CRED_ID ";
```

This other doesn't, and I can't understand why (all examples I see around use the exact same syntax):

```
string command =
   "SELECT cred.* " +
   "FROM TB_CREDENTIALS cred " +
   "INNER JOIN TB_REL_USERS_CREDENTIALS rel ON cred.CRED_ID = rel.REL_USR_CRED_CRED_ID " +
   "INNER JOIN TB_USERS usr ON usr.USR_ID = rel.REL_USR_CRED_USER_ID ";
```

The exception given is the following `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException`:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'cred.CRED_ID = rel.REL_USR_CRED_CRED_ID INNER JOIN TB_USERS usr ON usr.USR_ID = rel.REL_USR_CRED_USER_I' `(message is cut here)`

Version and details:

- The database is a `.accdb` file created on Access 2010
- The connection is created in C# with `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection`
- The connection provider is `"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"`

(This seems like a useless query, but of course I'll add a `WHERE usr.SOME_FIELD = some_condition`)

Comment: Please validate my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Of course :) -- Waiting for the time limit.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! And thank you. I am new to answering questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"For multi-table joins, you have to nest the extra joins in brackets:"

[SQL multiple join statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854969/sql-multiple-join-statement)